# How to get the ReturnValue after the command has finished?

Tags: powershell, error-handling

How do I get the `ReturnValue` as shown in the screen shot I've added ?

I'm trying to create a log file that will display the error codes to check if each command in my script ended successfully or there is an issue to take care of. I've tried to search Google but all I could find was how to return value from a function but not the `ReturnValue` I need here:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Don't know which exact command you are running, so you will not get an exact answer.   But here it goes.

First run this command from powershell and note the output is similar to yours, with Genus, Species, Phylum etc.

```
get-wmiobject softwarelicensingproduct -filter "LicenseStatus='1'"
```

Then (encapsulate) your command inside parenthesis and add (a)`.ReturnValue`, similar to how I added (a)`.Description` in the second line.  When run it only returns the description value.

```
(get-wmiobject softwarelicensingproduct -filter "LicenseStatus='1'").Description
```

So basically just wrap `(parenthesis).ReturnValue` around your command and see `70` for $profit.

Comment: Some info on using parenthesis in sub-expressions - http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html  - http://huddledmasses.org/parenthesis-in-powershell/